# Got error after installing passenger with apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I installed passenger with apache on centos7.

After I installed successfully, I put this passenger config in httpd.conf of apache, then I restart apache again, I still get error as below,

```
Jan 25 04:11:14 ip-10-0-0-201 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jan 25 04:11:14 ip-10-0-0-201 httpd[26168]: httpd: Syntax error on line 351 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/buildout/apache2...
Jan 25 04:11:14 ip-10-0-0-201 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 25 04:11:14 ip-10-0-0-201 kill[26170]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jan 25 04:11:14 ip-10-0-0-201 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 25 04:11:14 ip-10-0-0-201 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jan 25 04:11:14 ip-10-0-0-201 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jan 25 04:11:14 ip-10-0-0-201 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

This is my `httpd.conf`

```
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on    
LoadModule passenger_module /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/passenger-5.1.12
  PassengerDefaultRuby /home/centos/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/ruby
</IfModule>
# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

If i remove code above from `httpd.conf`, I can  still restart apache successfully.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: are setting up the rails application ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed passenger gem for the ruby version you are using? Because it looks like you haven't!